# I am trying to make procedural spines but they do not work each time I draw a new curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I am trying to create a quick way to make spines along drawn curves but am somewhat new to geometry nodes. The circled spine was the first and the other three are new. Each one seam to act differently and I do not understand how to make them all act the same. The segments should scale along the length of the curve from bottom to top. What am I missing? Thank you in advance for your response(s).[image]

Comment: instead of resample curve with count, try length. And please, next time use a node tree we can easily read...and even better: provide your blend file so we can test out our solution proposal. thx.